# How do you make integers get added properly in Jframe?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a [BMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) calculator in Java. However first I'm playing around with some Jframe stuff and it seems to not be working properly.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BMI_Calculator() {
   JPanel jp = new JPanel();
   JLabel jl = new JLabel();
   JTextField jt1 = new JTextFeild(30);
   JButton jb = new JButton("Click here for BMI value");
enter code here
enter private BMI_Calculator() {
         setTitle("BMI_Calculator");
         setVisible(true);
         setSize(400, 300);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         jp.add(jt1);
         jt1.addActionListener(e -> {
            int Height_input = jt1.getHeight();
            jl.setText("Your height + 1 " + Get_BMI(Height_input));
        });
        jp.add(jb);

        jb.addActionListener(e -> {
              int input = jt1.getHeight();
              jl.setText("Your height + 1 " + Get_BMI(input));
       }) 
       jp.add(jl);
       add(jp);
  }



private static int Get_BMI(int height) {
// adds one to height.

int sum = 1;
sum += height;
return sum;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new BMI_Calculator();
}
}
```

So when I run it shows the textfeild, and it shows the button, the thing is when I run it and if for example I enter 23 in the textfeild, I get back, "Your height + 1 is 21." What's happening that it's giving me that response, my Get_BMI method should be taking the height and adding one to it but it's not doing that. Even when I just click the button without putting any numbers into the textfeild, I get "Your height + 1 is 21." Please help get the integers to add properly. Thanks.

Comment: `jt1.getHeight()` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Use `jt1.getText()` to get the text from the text field then convert it to an `int`

Answer (score 1):

`jt1.getHeight()` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Use `jt1.getText()` to get the text from the text field then convert it to an `int`

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(30);
    JButton jb = new JButton("Click here for BMI value");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new BMICalculatorPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BMICalculatorPane extends JPanel {

        private BMICalculatorPane() {
            jp.add(jt1);
            jt1.addActionListener(e -> {
                calculateBMI();
            });
            jb.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                calculateBMI();
            });
            jp.add(jb);
            jp.add(jl);
            add(jp);
        }

        protected void calculateBMI() {
            try {
                int Height_input = Integer.parseInt(jt1.getText());
                jl.setText("Your height + 1 " + getBMI(Height_input));
            } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BMICalculatorPane.this, "Invalid input", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        private static int getBMI(int height) {
            int sum = 1;
            sum += height;
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```